# Newton’s method pth root- MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Newton’s method can be used to calculate the p-th root of a positive real number. Write a Matlab function myrootp.m which calculates a^(1/p) for any a> 0 and a positive integer p. The function should stop when abs((Xk^(p)/a)-1)<10^(-15).

I used the following code but I cannot find the error:

```
   function root1 = root1( a,X0,p)

    Xk=X0;
    fd= p*Xk^(p-1);
    f=(Xk^p)-a;
    if a<0 
then disp('Error:a must be positive and real')
    else
for k=1:p
    if abs(Xk^p/a-1)<10^(-15)
        then return disp('Error');
    else            
    Xk1=Xk-f/fd;
    Xk=Xk1;
    fd= p*Xk^(p-1);
    f=(Xk^p)-a;
    end
end

  end

  root1 = Xk;
  return
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to point out for those who are unfamiliar with this algorithm that this is finding the [nth root of a number using Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm).

---

Back to your problem, there are two errors:

1. There is no such keyword as `then` in MATLAB.  Get rid of it.
2. You'll want to iterate **until** the error is as you specified.  You are looping for as many times as there is the power `p`, and it's highly possible that the algorithm can converge before then, or the worst case require more iterations than `p` to converge.

Making these two changes:

```
function root1 = root1(a,X0,p)

Xk=X0;
fd= p*Xk^(p-1);
f=(Xk^p)-a;
if a<0 
    disp('Error:a must be positive and real')
else
    while true
        if abs(Xk^p/a-1)<10^(-15)
            break;
        else            
            Xk1=Xk-f/fd;
            Xk=Xk1;
            fd= p*Xk^(p-1);
            f=(Xk^p)-a;
        end
    end
end

root1 = Xk;
```

---

To test this out, using an initial guess of 5 or `X0=5`, and we want to find the square root of 10 (`a = 10, p = 2`), we get:

```
>> format long g;
>> root1(10, 5, 2)

ans =

      3.16227766016838
```

Comparing this with MATLAB's `sqrt` function, we get:

```
>> format long g;
>> sqrt(10)

ans =

      3.16227766016838
```